# Probability Distributions "related" to normal distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

I am tutoring a student and I am unable to determine what "related" means in this problem.  Im thinking just the Z and students t are normally distributed but arent chi squared and the F test related to a normal probability distribution even though they are not normally distributed?  I read a scientific paper on the G distribution and still cant tell if it is normally distributed or "related" to a normal distribution.  Neither can i make sure about morphets q.  Can anyone enlighten me please.

Choose all probability distributions which are theoretically related to the normal probability distribution.

A) G

B) Morphet's Q

C) Chi Square

D) Z

E) Student's t

F) F

I am claiming that only Z and Students t are normally distributed

Comment: Chi-square is the distribution of a squared normal r.v., for instance.

Comment: If a distribution has finite variance, apply the central limit theorem.

Comment: "Theoretically related" is hopelessly ambiguous.  Every probability distribution can be related to a normal distribution in the sense that there is some function $f$ such that if $Z \sim N(0,1)$, $f(Z)$ has the given distribution.

Comment: yea,  related is not a good term here

Comment: Agreed, not good. But fairly clear at a certain elementary level. Note that Student's t distribution is _not_ normal; for large degrees of freedom, say $\nu > 30$ (or $50,$ depending on the discussion), $\mathsf{T}(\nu)$ is approximately normal. Also, for sufficiently large $\nu,\, Q$ is approx norm. // The definition of chi-sq, t, and F in terms of standard normal, makes these distributions useful in analyzing data from normal populations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Student's t, Chi-squared, and F are 'related' to normal, even though they
are not normally distributed.

Let $Z_0, Z_1, \dots, Z_n$ be independently standard normal.
Then $Q = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n),$ the chi-squared
distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom.

Also, $T = \frac{Z_0}{\sqrt{Q/n}} \sim \mathsf{T}(n),$ Student's t distribution with
$n$ degrees of freedom.

Finally, if $Q_1 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n)$ and independently
$Q_2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(m),$ then $F = \frac{Q_1/n}{Q_2/m}
\sim \mathsf{F}(n,m),$ Snedecor's F distribution with numerator
degrees of freedom $n$ and denominator degrees of freedom $m.$

$Z$ is a frequently used notation for $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ the
standard normal distribution. The letter $Q$ is my personal favorite
notation for a chi-squared distribution.

For more details and graphs for various parameters, you can find Wikipedia pages on each of these distributions.
You are on your own with $G$ and Morphet's $Q$.

---

Here are histograms of 100,000 realizations of each of $\mathsf{Chisq}(4),\, \mathsf{T}(5), \,
\mathsf{F}(15,20)$ generated as discussed above. Red curves are the density
functions of these distributions. [Formal proofs use moment generating functions and multivariate transformations.]

[image]

*Note:* For archival purposes, the R code used to make the plots is shown below.

```
set.seed(330);  m = 10^5 
par(mfrow=c(1,3)) # enable three panels per plot
 z.0 = rnorm(m)    # generate standard normals (three lines)
 z.1 = rnorm(m); z.2 = rnorm(m); z.3 = rnorm(m); z.4 = rnorm(m)
 z.5 = rnorm(m); z.6 = rnorm(m); z.7 = rnorm(m); z.8 = rnorm(m); z.9 = rnorm(m)
 q.4 = z.1^2 + z.2^2 + z.3^2 + z.4^2  # CHISQ(4) from four indep NORM(0,1)
 q.5 = z.5^2 + z.6^2 + z.7^2 + z.8^2 + z.9^2 # CHISQ(5) from five
 hist(q.4, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="CHISQ(4)")
   curve(dchisq(x,4), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
 t = z.0/sqrt(q.5/5)  # T(5) from NORM(0,1) and CHISQ(5)
 hist(t, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2", main="T(5)", ylim=c(0,.4))
   curve(dt(x,5), add=T, lwd=2, col="red", n=10001)
 q.15 = rchisq(m, 15); q.20 = rchisq(m, 20) # CHISQ(15) & CHISQ(20) sim directly
 f = (q.15/15)/(q.20/20) # F(15, 20) from CHISQ(15) & CHISQ(20)
 hist(f, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="F(15,20)", ylim=c(0,1))
   curve(df(x, 15, 20), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Sorry if this question is too broad: Other than some basic cases like adding standard normals or translates/scalings. How does one determine the distribution of a variable, say a ratio of normals? Do we use the Moment G.Fs? If this is too long for an answer here, if you could please give me a ref?

Comment: As I said in my Answer "Formal proofs use moment generating functions and multivariate transformations." You can find the full mathematical development in most mathematical statistics texts. // Of course, my simulation is not a proof, but it does illustrate the ideas for the particular cases I simulated.

Comment: I really appreciate your expertise on this question